# Rails : soap4r - Error while running wsdl2ruby.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, soap4r, wsdl2ruby

when I execute 
Mathieu$ /Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb path --wsdl https://www.arello.com/webservice/verify.cfc?wsdl --type client --force

I get

at depth 0 - 20: unable to get local issuer certificate
F, [2010-05-06T10:41:11.040288 #35933] FATAL -- app: Detected an exception. Stopping ... SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:247:in `connect'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:247:in`ssl_connect'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:639:in `connect'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/timeout.rb:128:in`timeout'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:631:in `connect'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:522:in`query'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:147:in `query'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:953:in`do_get_block'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:765:in `do_request'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:848:in`protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:764:in `do_request'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:833:in`follow_redirect'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/httpclient-2.1.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:519:in `get_content'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/xmlSchema/importer.rb:73:in`fetch'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/xmlSchema/importer.rb:36:in `import'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/importer.rb:18:in`import'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:206:in `import'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/lib/wsdl/soap/wsdl2ruby.rb:36:in`run'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:46:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/logger.rb:659:in`start'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/soap4r-1.5.8/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:137
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:19:in `load'
/Users/Mathieu/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin/wsdl2ruby.rb:19
I, [2010-05-06T10:41:11.040855 #35933]  INFO -- app: End of app. (status: -1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way to do this is to use a tool like curl to get the WSDL into a file and then just ask wsdl2ruby to create your SOAP client using this file. Ruby is much pickier about SSL certificates than the command line utilities and there are ways of using HTTPS in code, but I think you would need to unpick the code in the utility. All you need are the definitions.

This also has the not inconsiderable advantage of allowing you to keep the WSDL you used in your source code control system as a reference.